# Reset all bits in a c bitfield

Tags: c, bit-fields

I thought that using a C bitfield instead of a `int` along with a bunch of `#define`s would give a better-to-read code and reduce the need for adapting existing code when adding new fields. Is there any possibility to reset all Bits in a C bitfield to zero with a single command as the `int`-`#define`-method provides?

Examples:

```
#define MYFLAG_1 0x01
#define MYFLAG_2 0x02
#define MYFLAG_3 0x04

int myflags = MYFLAG_1 | MYFLAG_3;

/* Reset: */
myflags = 0;
```

versus

```
struct {
    int flag_1 : 1;
    int flag_2 : 1;
    int flag_3 : 1;
} myflags;

myflags.flag_1 = 1;
myflags.flag_3 = 1;

/* Reset: */
myflags.flag_1 = 0;
myflags.flag_2 = 0;
myflags.flag_3 = 0;
```

Adding an additional flag to the field would require no change (apart from the #define) in the existing code of the first example but would require code to reset the additional flag field.

Comment: I'd have to add the new value a) to the bitfield and b) to the function.

Comment: What about `memset(&my_flags, 0, sizeof(myflags))`

Comment: @urzeit I'm not following. You don't have to add anything.

Comment: If I add a new flag to the `struct` I have to add it to the function, too, right?

Comment: @Coconop: Does the standard guarantee for that to work?

Comment: Or perhaps `*(int*)&myflags = 0;`

Comment: @Krister Andersson: That will not work if the bitfield grows beyond the size of an `int`.

Comment: Whats about using `unions`? You could have an `UINT` or `ULONG` sharing the same memory with the bit field. Setting the number to zero will also null the bits. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497345/is-there-a-way-to-access-individual-bits-with-a-union (for your use case, limited to length of the numerical variable, but up to 64bits may be sufficient)

Comment: `#define RESET(bits) memset(&bits, 0, sizeof(bits))`

Comment: @KristerAndersson I believe that (`*(int*)&myflags = 0;`) breaks the strict aliasing rule and in addition types might have different alignment restrictions.

Comment: I don't have a standard reference to back me up on this, but I don't see any limitation for this solution in your use-case.

Comment: @user694733 - Yes that could be the case, I was thinking that the structure will be padded to 4bytes. Of course this won't work if that isn't the case or the size of the structure grows bigger then an int.

Comment: Your bitfiels are small. That's good. There is nothing to prevent you from defining a `bits_on` instance of the field and a `bits_off` instance. Then turning all on/off is a simple of `memcpy` from the one desired, or a simple `or` or `and` with the one needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply suggest:

```
memset(&my_flags, 0, sizeof(myflags));
```

This way, you can still add fields to your structure, they will be reset thanks to `sizeof`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to expand my comment to an answer:

Using a union, you can have a numerical variable and your bit field sharing the same memory:

```
typedef  union{
    struct {
        int flag_1 : 1;
        int flag_2 : 1;
        int flag_3 : 1;
    };
    unsigned int value;
} MyBitField;

// ...
MyBitField myflags;

myflags.flag_1 = 1;
myflags.flag_3 = 1;

/* Reset: */
//myflags.flag_1 = 0;
//myflags.flag_2 = 0;
//myflags.flag_3 = 0;

myflags.value = 0;
```

Now, you can easily set all bits to 0. The union will always occupy the amount of memory the largest object in it needs. So, if you need more bits than an INT has, you may also use a `long` or `long long`.

I haven't seen unions in "computer programming" until now, but for microcontrollers, they are used quite often.

Comment: Should be mentioned that union aliasing is only guaranteed to work  on C99 or newer. There is also possibility that bitfield and value member do not alias: Compiler is free to use larger type for bit-field, in this case it could even be `unsigned long long`.

Comment: I once asked a similiar question regarding using a union and a struct liek this and got the answer that this is undefined behavior. allthough very likely to work

Comment: I like the idea of using an union - and have used it quite often. It just feels better then memset(..) - working on micro-controllers this adds too much overhead. If the bit fields go beyond an int - I can't see any reason why you can't just use an array for value - i.e int value[ 2 ]; then clear each int within it.