# Clear just bit field members of a struct?

Tags: c, bit-fields

I have a `struct` like the following:

```
struct Foo {
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int flag_1 : 1;
    unsigned int flag_2 : 1;
    unsigned int flag_3 : 1;
    // Some arbitrary number of further flags. Code is
    // automatically generated and number will vary.
    // Notably, it may be more than an int's worth.
    int some_data;
    float some_more_data;
    // ...
};
```

From time to time, I need to reset all the flags to zero while preserving the rest of the struct. One way is obviously to set each flag to 0 individually, but it feels like there ought to be a way to do it in one fell swoop. Is that possible?

(Note that I am open to not using bit fields, but this is code that will sometimes run on memory-contrained systems, so the memory savings are very appealing.)

**Edit:**

There is a similar question here: [Reset all bits in a c bitfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121427/reset-all-bits-in-a-c-bitfield)

However, the struct in that question is *entirely* bitfields. I cannot simply `memset` the entire struct to zero here, and the other answer involving unions is not guaranteed to work, especially if there are more than an int's worth of flags.

Comment: Can't you use an array of unsigned int for flags? You can iterate over flags

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121427/reset-all-bits-in-a-c-bitfield

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset all bits in a c bitfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121427/reset-all-bits-in-a-c-bitfield)

Comment: @AbhayAravinda That is a valid option, but I'd like to avoid it if possible for the memory savings.

Comment: @yano I did see that question, but the struct there is entirely bitfields. I can't just clear the whole struct in this case, and the answer involving unions seems unsafe.

Comment: Why are you using int for flags? won't char occupy lesser bytes?

Comment: @AbhayAravinda `unsigned int` in this case is not referring to the actual size in memory, just how the value is interpreted. (I'm not 100% sure if it affects alignment boundaries.) The `:1` determines how many bits are actually used. See [this bit field primer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a separate `struct` for the flags:

```
struct Foo_flags {
    unsigned int flag_1 : 1;
    unsigned int flag_2 : 1;
    unsigned int flag_3 : 1;
    // ...
};

struct Foo {
    unsigned int id;
    struct Foo_flags flags;
    int some_data;
    float some_more_data;
    // ...
};
```

Or even a simpler nested `struct`:

```
struct Foo {
    unsigned int id;

    struct {
        unsigned int flag_1 : 1;
        unsigned int flag_2 : 1;
        unsigned int flag_3 : 1;
        // ...
    } flags;

    int some_data;
    float some_more_data;
    // ...
};
```

Then, later in your code:

```
struct Foo x;
// ...
x.flags.flag_1 = 1;
// ...
memset(&x.flags, 0, sizeof(x.flags));
```

Answer (score 4):

With some minor adjustments, you can use the [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) macro to find the beginning and end of the "flag" data within the structure, then use `memset` to clear the relevant memory. *(Note that you cannot use `offsetof` directly on bitfields, hence the addition of the `flag_beg` member!)*

Here's a working example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>  // defines offsetof
#include <string.h>  // declares memset

struct Foo {
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int flag_beg;    // Could be unsigned char to save space
    unsigned int flag_1 : 1;
    unsigned int flag_2 : 1;
    unsigned int flag_3 : 1;
    unsigned int flag_end;    // Could be unsigned char to save space
    // Some arbitrary number of further flags. Code is
    // automatically generated and number will vary.
    // Notably, it may be more than an int's worth.
    int some_data;
    float some_more_data;
    // ...
};

#define FBEG (offsetof(struct Foo, flag_beg))
#define FEND (offsetof(struct Foo, flag_end))

int main()
{
    struct Foo f;
    f.id = 3; f.flag_1 = 1; f.flag_2 = 0; f.flag_3 = 1;
    f.some_data = 33; f.some_more_data = 16.2f;

    printf("%u %u %u %u %d %f\n", f.id, f.flag_1, f.flag_2, f.flag_3, f.some_data, f.some_more_data);
    memset((char*)(&f) + FBEG, 0, FEND - FBEG);
    printf("%u %u %u %u %d %f\n", f.id, f.flag_1, f.flag_2, f.flag_3, f.some_data, f.some_more_data);
    return 0;
}
```